# How to export data from rails api to xls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, api, xls

I have an json api built with rails.
This is url: https://kazatomprom-backend.herokuapp.com/organizations/suzak/blocks/1/notes

I want to export data to xls. But this data must be customized according to model attributes.

```
id| volume_value|user
 1|        887  |zhanabek@gmail.com
 2|        897  |john@gmail.com
```

I found some solution, but it requires the view, but I don't need a view, because this is api. So, how to export data using only api?

Comment: "but I don't need a view, because this is api" - hint: "a view" is not necessarily "an html/erb view". Can be jbuilder view or excel builder view or anything else. A "view" is just something that helps you generate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work (It uses csv data to write to xls file):

```
CSV.open('foo.xls', "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ['id','volume_value','user']
  JSON.parse(json).each do |hash|
    csv << [hash['id'],hash['volume_value'],hash['user']['email']]
  end
end
```

Comment: Where i should put this code. In model? Next question! how it will work? when i open url, the browser will suggest me to download a file?

Comment: you can use `send_file` to make users download xls file on accessing the url.

Comment: where I should put this code. In controller or model? Sorry, I am noob in rails, but anyway could you answer me properly

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem `acts_as_xlsx` you might want to see

https://github.com/randym/acts_as_xlsx

It allows you to call `.to_xlsx` method on `ActiveRecord` result like this

```
Posts.where(created_at > Time.now-30.days).to_xlsx
```

**How to Use**

Add the gem to your Gemfile and bundle install
   gem 'acts_as_xlsx'

```
# app/models/post.rb
   class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
     acts_as_xlsx
   end

 # app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
   class PostsController < ApplicationController
     # GET posts/xlsx     
     def xlsx
       p = Post.to_xlsx
       p.serialize('public/downloads/posts.xlsx')
       send_file 'public/downloads/posts.xlsx', :type=>"application/xlsx"
     end
   end

 # dont forget to add posts/xslx to your routes!
```